# Java 8 optional time part not working

Tags: java, java-8, datetime-format, java-time

I am trying to create date time format for optional time part currently I implemented this

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.text.ParseException;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(Ideone.getDate("2017-07-01T00:00:00.0Z"));
        System.out.println(Ideone.getDate("2017-07-01T00:00:00.00Z"));
        System.out.println(Ideone.getDate("2017-07-01T00:00:00.000Z"));
    }
    
    public static LocalDateTime getDate(String date) {
        try {
           
            DateTimeFormatter formatter2 =
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS]'Z'");
            LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter2);
            
            
            return ldt;
           
        } catch (DateTimeParseException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And having output

> null
>
> 2017-07-01T00:00
>
> 2017-07-01T00:00

Now my question is, why date with 1 time fraction is not working and it is working with 2 and 3 fractions? should it entertain 1,2 and 3 fractions? or only 3 fractions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have no idea why as of yet, but this pattern seems to solve your issue: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.S[SS]]'Z'");`

Comment: Thanks @Mena but in your opinion is this `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS]'Z'` for 3 or non fraction or upto 3 fraction?

Comment: I think it's poorly specified in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns). This is why I commented with something that *might* work for you, but I am unable to actually answer your question.

Comment: Do you want to know just why this happens? Do you also want a formatter that works in all cases?

Comment: @Hugo actually I want to know, because i have workaround of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS][.SS][.S]'Z'` to support upto 3 fractions

Comment: Ok. Not direclty related, but it's better to use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS][.SS][.S]X` - the `X` will parse the offset (`Z` is the [UTC designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC) and although `LocalDateTime` discards it, it's better to don't treat it as a literal)

Comment: I fear you have discovered a subtile bug. For comparison: Using my lib Time4J works as intended with your pattern: `LocalDateTime ldt = ChronoFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS]'Z'", PatternType.CLDR, Locale.ROOT, PlainTimestamp.axis(TemporalType.LOCAL_DATE_TIME)).parse(input);`

Comment: According to [DateTimeFormatterBuilder javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-), `SSS` is equivalent to `appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 3, 3, false)`, so it should accept exactly 3 digits. It really seems like a bug.

Comment: @Hugo I have also tried to debug. The min width of 3 is only important during strict parsing. But the parser is not strict (tested). Anyway, even in strict mode, the parser would be expected to fail inside the optional section, and then per spec not abort but keep the old position (at the dot) and try to jump to the next pattern instruction (here "Z" as literal, which would then fail because the input has the dot instead of "Z at that position => different cause). Nothing like that, so it is obviously a bug.

Comment: @MenoHochschild That's an "interesting" bug. For any pattern with `n` digits, if works for inputs with `n` and `n - 1`. One alternative to parse only 3 digits is to use `appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3)`.

Comment: @Hugo Or simply: `appendFraction(NANO_OF_SECOND, 1, 3, false)`

Comment: It's a bug that seem to affect `FractionPrinterParser` class. What happens is it expects to see at least 3 characters after a dot, and it sees them, i.e. `00Z`. It is then satisfied with this and doesn't check whether those three characters are actually parsable by it, so after it runs into a `Z`, it just stops and doesn't return any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug. The millisecond part of datetime parsing seems to be in general buggy in Java 8, see [this issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8031085) and its duplicates.

Relevant quote:

> Worse however is that the SSS pattern has therefore ended up using
> strict mode when lenient mode would be appropriate. As it currently
> stands, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hhmmss.SSS") requires three
> digits for milliseconds, when it was originally intended to require 0
> to 9 (the lenient behaviour).
>
> Given that the current implementation requires three digits for SSS, it is thus very surprising that adjacent value parsing does not apply.

But you seem to have found a case where requirement mentioned above does not apply either. In addition, even though the issue above is in state "fixed", your example seems to have issues in *both* java 8 and java 9:

```
>java -version
java version "9"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)

>javac Ideone.java

>java Ideone
null
2017-07-01T00:00
2017-07-01T00:00

>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin"\javac Ideone.java

>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin"\java Ideone
null
2017-07-01T00:00
2017-07-01T00:00
```

> should it entertain 1,2 and 3 fractions? or only 3 fractions?

Based on the quote, it should be only 3, though originally intended to be 0-9.

Comment: This is indeed a bug, but it's not related to issue you've linked. This one has to do with literals at the end of a string (see my comment on question). Last I checked, this was not reported to JDK guys at all.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I didn't claim it's the issue I linked, did I? I pointed out *the comments of it* about how the literals should work.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS][.S]'Z'")`

Basically it's saying to first check for the long-form of 2+ fraction-of-second digits, otherwise if that optional field is not present, check for the optional field of a single fraction-of-second digit specified by `[.S]`

Comment: "question is, why date with 1 time fraction is not working and it is working with 2 and 3 fractions? should it entertain 1,2 and 3 fractions? or only 3 fractions?" - how is this an answer?

Answer (score -2):

Reason why you are getting null when you pass this is

> "2017-07-01T00:00:00.0Z"

you have told the parser to expect 3 char format (see below **.SSS**)

DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS]'Z'");

If you change it to **.SS**, it should work, however your last input i.e. **2017-07-01T00:00:00.000Z** will break. You may want to include some logic to handle different formats

Comment: but question is, why it works for `.SS` and not for `.S`. my pattern is with `.SSS` so it should work with only `.SSS`