# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException when parsing year

Tags: java, java-8

**jdk used : 1.8**

Not sure what is the issue, configuredFormat is valid one, inputTime is also valid one, really confused what is the issue.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String configuredFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS";
        String inputTime = "20200203164553123";

        DateTimeFormatter dt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(configuredFormat);
        DateTimeFormatter strictTimeFormatter = dt.withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
        try {
            LocalTime.parse(inputTime, strictTimeFormatter);
            System.out.println("success");
        } catch (DateTimeParseException | NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Exception I am Getting :

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20200203164553123' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalTime.parse(LocalTime.java:441)
    at com.Test.main(Test.java:20)
```

Comment: Try using LocalDateTime?

Comment: I can reproduce the error. If I put a space somewhere in the pattern and the format, the error goes away. Looks like it can't parse a date with the year and the milliseconds in the same string.

Comment: @Michael 
System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)
Time Zone:                 (UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi

Comment: @Minn  Tried didn't worked

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lucky for you, there is an **exact** bug report which uses the exact same pattern that you're trying. Who better to explain than the JDK maintainers?

[JDK-8031085](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8031085)

> Workaround
>
> ```
> DateTimeFormatter dtf = new
> DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
>     .appendPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
>     .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND,3)
>     .toFormatter()
> ```
>
> Adjacent value parsing is generally a hard problem. It is intended to
>   handle the case where the first element is variable width (the year)
>   and all other elements are fixed width (month, day etc). However, the
>   "S" pattern letter is a fraction, not a value. Specifically, the
>   fraction can be variable width - more or less than three digits are
>   possible options. Given the general case of a variable width year and
>   a variable width millisecond, it is not possible to determine which of
>   the two fields was intended to be variable.
>
> Having said that, the implementation (and javadoc) have not ended up
>   as I intended. The description of "fraction" in DateTimeFormatter
>   describes actions in strict and lenient mode, but there is no way to
>   access strict or lenient mode when using
>   DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(). This is a documentation bug that should
>   be fixed by removing the discussion of strict vs lenient.
>
> Worse however is that the SSS pattern has therefore ended up using
>   strict mode when lenient mode would be appropriate. As it currently
>   stands, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hhmmss.SSS") requires three
>   digits for milliseconds, when it was originally intended to require 0
>   to 9 (the lenient behaviour).
>
> I tried changing the whole of the DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern() method
>   to use lenient parsing, and it broke no tests (which is bad in its own
>   way). This might be a valid fix, but only if included in JDK 8, as
>   once people adapt to the strict parsing it will be hard to make it
>   lenient.
>
> Given that the current implementation requires three digits for SSS,
>   it is thus very surprising that adjacent value parsing does not apply.

Comment: Oh, cool. Seems like there is a JDK bug fix that addressed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46321529/java-8-optional-time-part-not-working after all.

Answer (score 4):

Actually I agree format should be valid... this seems to be confirmed as I tried with both oracle java 8 and 9 runtime, and with java 9 it does not happen. (I tried IBM jre 8 too and it works as well)

```
        System.out.println( System.getProperty( "java.vendor" )+" - "+System.getProperty( "java.version" ) );
        String configuredFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS";
        String inputTime = "20200203164553123";
        DateTimeFormatter dt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(configuredFormat);
        DateTimeFormatter strictTimeFormatter = dt.withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
        try {
            //System.out.println( dt.parse( inputTime ) );
            LocalTime.parse(inputTime, strictTimeFormatter);
            System.out.println("success");
        } catch (DateTimeParseException | NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Output

```
Oracle Corporation - 9.0.4
success


IBM Corporation - 1.8.0_211
success

Oracle Corporation - 1.8.0_172
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20200203164553123' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.LocalTime.parse(Unknown Source)
    at test.Test2.main(Test2.java:19)
```

Comment: it is working with java 11 as well, i already tried that, but there is constraint to use java 1.8 version for some reason, is it any work around as such with java 8.